# Auf was bezieht sich „den“ hier?

Tags: pronoun

> Die Rente vermindert sich um 0,3 von Hundert für den vollen Monat, **den** der Versorgungsfall vor Vollendung des 65. Lebensjahres eintritt.

Auf was bezieht sich „den“ hier?

Comment: This looks wrong. Can you provide a bit more textual context?

Comment: With the exception of the tiny correction as pointed out by tohuwawohu this looks like typical burocratic German.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es <s>muss</s> sollte "für **jeden** vollen Monat" lauten (siehe etwa [§ 18 Abs. 2 Nr. 2 BetrAVG](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/betravg/__18.html)). Mit "den" statt "jeden" ist der Sinn nicht eindeutig; "für **den** vollen Monat" würde man eher so verstehen, dass sich die Rente *nur für einen bestimmten Monat mindert*. Die Formulierung wird damit nicht schöner, nur klarer.

Korrigiert man die ursprüngliche Fassung wie vorgeschlagen, dann ist besser erkennbar, dass sich "den" auf "jeden vollen Monat" bezieht.

Hintergrund ist wohl, dass jemand ab einem bestimmten Zeitpunkt ("Versorgungsfall", in etwa gleichbedeutend mit "Versicherungsfall") Anspruch auf eine Rentenzahlung hat. Offen ist jedoch die Höhe der Rentenzahlung; der zitierte Satz betrifft exakt diese Frage.

Die Regelung sagt dazu aus, dass sich die Höhe der Rentenzahlung mindert, wenn der Versorgungsfall vor dem 65. Geburtstag eintritt. Dabei ist die Rentenzahlung um so geringer, je früher der Versorgungsfall eintritt. Jeder volle Monat schlägt dabei mit 0,3 % zu Buche.

Comment: An sich hast du Recht, aber "falsch" ist anders. Äpfel kosten auch "drei Euro das Kilo", obwohl *jedes* Kilo drei Euro kostet. Ich denke, man könnte die Formulierung so wie im Original durchgehen lassen. Klar: Besser geht immer.

Comment: @tofro: stimmt - ich ersetze besser "muss" durch "sollte"...

Comment: Wie würde der Satz richtig lauten: „Der Versorgungsfall tritt vor Vollendung des 65. Lebensjahres jeden vollen Monat ein.“ ?

Comment: @Jean: Dieser Satz ergibt für mich keinen Sinn. In Deiner ursprünglichen Frage wird der Eintritt des Versorgungsfalls **vorausgesetzt**. **Wann** der Versorgungsfall eintritt, muss sich aus anderen Regeln ergeben. Der Satz aus Deiner ursprünglichen Frage regelt nur, was passiert, **wenn** der Versorgungsfall vor dem 65. Geburtstag **eingetreten ist**.

Comment: Sorry, Ihre ursprüngliche Antwort ist super erklärt, ich wollte mehr über Satzbau lernen. Denn ein Relativsatz kann zu einem Hauptsatz umformuliert werden durch Ersetzen von Pronomen. Z.B. „Ich gehe gern in die Kneipe, die neben meinem Haus ist.“, der Relativsatz kann zu „Die Kneipe ist neben meinem Haus.“ umformuliert werden, der immer noch einen Sinn ergibt. Aber wie könnte der Relativsatz „den der Versorgungsfall vor Vollendung des 65. Lebensjahres eintritt.“ zu einem Hauptsatz umformuliert werden?

Comment: @Jean: Jetzt verstehe ich. Eine solche Umformulierung würde in etwa lauten: "_Der Versorgungsfall trat x volle Monate vor Vollendung des 65. Lebensjahrs ein. Daher mindert sich die Rente x-mal um 0,3 vom Hundert._" Das "x" steht für die Lücke, die im ursprünglichen Beispiel angelegt ist; denn diese Anzahl ist ja nicht bekannt. Es wird nur die Folge davon beschrieben. Das liegt an der Wenn-dann-Konstruktion. Analog: "Wenn es regnet, bleibe ich daheim" -> "Es regnet. Ich bleibe daheim".